# CakePHP route URL not found!

Tags: cakephp, routes

I am trying to do some custom routing on my site, but have been stuck for 2 days at a very silly issue. I have the following route configuration:

```
Router::connect('/your-solution/add-comment/*', array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' => 'add'));
Router::connect('/admin/your-solution/add-comment/*', array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' => 'add', 'admin' => true));
```

The problem is that when I try to load a URL formatted using the second route, it gives me a 404 not found.
The first rule works fine.

For both rules I have a separate element containing a form and pointing to a URL formatted after the respective rule. The only parameter for both actions is the solution id, which is "contained" in the wildcard.

What could possibly be the issue? Thank you very much for your help!

**EDIT:**

I found out another weird behaviour. When I access `/admin/your-solution/add-comment/3`, it goes to that action. But if I submit a form to that link, it displays a blank page, with Firebug informing me that the page was not found. Very strange...
Also, I have a similar route for editing comments. Both loading the edit form and saving the form work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem has been lying in a disabled input. After I've deleted this element, the form submits correctly and the target page is shown.

Just for my knowledge, why didn't the form submit if it had a disabled input in it?

Comment: Check out my comment above Linkyndy! It's because the SecurityComponent expects all the inputs to be created with the FormHelper (i.e.: $form->input()). If that's the field that's causing you trouble, you can add it to the $disabledFields array. Cheers!

Comment: I've checked your answer, but the form is created using the FormHelper. I've temporarily removed that field and everything works fine. Anyway, how to add the field to the $disabledFields array? From within the controller? Isn't there any method to disable a field in the view? And why does a disabled field produce that blank page and the 404 error?

Answer (score 6):

how are you?

In order to see exactly why isn't it working, go to your /app/config/core.php and seek for this line:

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

And make sure the value is set to "2". This way, it'll no longer give you a 404 error, but the actual issue, since in production mode (debug set to 0), all errors are masked with a 404 error.

Let me know!

Cheers!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for asking, I'm fine. The debug level is set to 2. The thing is, it doesn't show me an explicit 404 error, but shows me a blank page, and when I look in Firebug, it shows a 'page not found' error.

Comment: Are you using the Security component? If so, try adding in your CommentsController methods "beforeFilter", $this->Security->validatePost = false; and see if it works. If it works, then it's because something's modifying the _token the component generates. More at [cakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1296/Security-Component)

Answer (score 1):

In your core.php be sure

Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));

In your comments controller, be sure you have

```
function admin_add() {...}
```

Also try other ways of formatting Routing statement.

```
Router::connect('/admin/your-solution/add-comment', array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' => 'add', 'admin' => true));
```

The order of your route is also important. You may want to check that.

For debugging which route you are using when loading the URL, try adding this code to your app_controller.php file.

```
function __construct() {
    $route = Router::currentRoute();
    pr($route);
}
```

These are just some tips to hopefully help you move forward.

Comment: Thanks for all those tips! I have the first two. The route format you posted doesn't include any extra parameter (like the solution id which I need), therefore it doesn't work. What other alternative route formatting should I try? I think I've tried every possible combination. I even tried removing any other route beside this one, and still it couldn't find the page...